# Google App Engine's Web Application server and Apache Tomcat

Tags: google-app-engine, tomcat, application-server

I read this sentence in google resources for GAE : "Google App Engine has it's own Web Application Server for simulating in desktop environment", so, my question is: Can I deploy Google App Engine apps (in .war format) on TomCat?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the short answer is: it depends

according to the [app engine doc](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/creating):

> App Engine Java applications use the Java Servlet standard for
>   interacting with the web server environment.

so for a simple servlet app, it can be run on tomcat

but

> The App Engine runtime environment imposes some constraints to ensure
>   that your app can be scaled to multiple instances on App Engine's
>   distributed infrastructure

if you have used apis from app engine such as UserService, or Datastore then you are not able to run it on tomcat. in this case, you can use the development web server from app engine sdk for dev and test purpose.